# Switching between activities -> infinitie loop

Tags: android

I'm new to android and have a "little" problem.

I'm starting the main activity which extend the base class.
The base class starts my "Navigation" class... and in the navigation class i have an switch argument to choose, wich activity should be created - well, at this moment i had an infinitie loop and i have noe idea why..

It works fine when i'm using fragments but i'm want to use activities... Hope someone can help me :)

Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Base {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("boot", "MainActivity-onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Base

```
public class Base extends ActionBarActivity implements
    NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerCallback {

public NavigationDrawer mNavigationDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("boot", "Base-onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Set up the drawer
    mNavigationDrawer = (NavigationDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

    mNavigationDrawer.setUp((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),
            R.id.navigation_drawer);
}
```

Navigation

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends Fragment {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private NavigationDrawerCallback mCallbacks;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainer;

private boolean mUserLearnedNavigation;
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_NAVI = "navigation_learned";
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_position";

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("boot", "Nav - onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedNavigation = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_NAVI, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
} ... 
private void selectItem(int position) {
    Log.v("boot", "Nav - selectitem");
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainer);
    }

    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemClicked(position);
    }

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ExpensesActivity.class));
            break;
        default:
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you start an activity, your menu get recreated and thus the switch case get executed. You shouldn't call selectItem in the onCreate of your menu. If you want to keep the user navigation, you'll have to start the proper activity in MainActivity.

You can add a check to see if getActivity is an instance of the activity you want to start before calling startActivity so you don't run in infinite loop again.

Comment: Thanks! ;) BUt how can i handle my "problem". I want to use multiple activities instead of one activity with many fragments. Therefore i want use my "base" class which implement my navigation. How can i see, if getActivity is an instance? Sry i'm new to java/android :> I'm a "php developer"..^^